# Big $\theta$ of $x^2ln(x) + xln(x^2+1)$

Tags: computer-science

I am working on finding the big $\theta$ of $x^2ln(x) + xln(x^2+1)$ but have never done it before with logarithms.  How would I handle this problem?  I also know that n is big $\Omega$ of nln(n) which I feel has something to do with this question... This is what I have tried for big Oh but although it seems incorrect:

$x^2ln(x) + xln(x^2+1)  \le  x^2ln(x) + xln(x^2+1)$
$\le x^2ln(x(x^2+1)) \le x^2ln(x^3+x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final expression for $x \ge 2$ is less than or equal to $x^2\ln(x^4)= 4 x^2\ln(x)$.

Alternatively you could say for $x \ge 3$:

$$x^2\ln(x) + x\ln(x^2+1) \le x^2\ln(x) + x\ln(x^x) = x^2\ln(x)+ x^2\ln(x) = 2   x^2\ln(x)$$

Comment: Why would it be $x \ge 3$ ?

Comment: @Paradox: because $2^2+1 \gt 2^2$ but $3^2+1 \lt 3^3$